# Flash Catalyst - Export Component to FB

Tags: flash, air, components, builder, flashcatalyst

I'm working on an AIR project using Flash Builder.

There's a couple of component that I could see would be easy to generate using Flash Catalyst.

I can't see any way to export a Flex component/library (SWC) of some UI elements from Flash Catalyst.

All I can see is that I can export an entire project from there and import it as a full project in flex but I can't see any way to export individual components..

is there any way to do this?

(Not sure if I'm making sense.. you let me know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread from the adobe forum seems to answer my question...

http://forums.adobe.com/message/2043412

This is very good too

http://www.themorphicgroup.com/blog/2009/06/23/adobe-flash-builder-and-catalyst-tips-tricks-and-hacks/